# Show no norm on $X = \{ P: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: P\,\, \text{is a polynomial} \}$ such that $X$ is a Banach space

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Let $$X = \{ P: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}: P\,\,  \text{is a polynomial} \}.$$ Use the Baire Category theorem to prove that there exists no norm on $X$ such that $X$ is a Banach space.

My attempt:

Suppose, towards a contradiction, that $X$ is a Banach space. Consider $$A_n = \{ P \in X: \text{degree of $P \leq n$} \}.$$ Note that $A_n$ is a proper subspace of $X$ so it has empty interior. Hence, $A_n$ is meager. But $$X = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_n$$ so $X$ is meager which contradicts $X$ being complete. So there is no norm on $X$ such that $X$ is a Banach space.

Is this correct? It feels like something is missing perhaps.

Comment: Correct.  There is no Banach space with countably infinite Hamel dimension.

Comment: @GEdgar The proof is correct though? Or is it missing something?

Comment: Maybe add the remark that a finite-dimensional subspace is complete, and therefore closed---as a reason that it has empty interior.

Comment: @GEdgar: Or rather, as the reason that the *closure* of $A_n$ has empty interior - which is the sufficient condition to be meager.